# How to find the probability there are 11 or more cars?

Tags: probability, statistics

During rush hour the number of cars passing through a particular intersection has a Poisson distribution with an average of 540 per hour.
Find the probability there are 11 or more cars?
The answer is 0.006669.
I don not know how to deal with this kind of question.
Please help.Thank you very much.

Comment: Eleven or more cars in what amount of time?  Without that we don't have enough information.

Comment: Jing must mean 11 or more cars in one hour. And the answer is probably meant to be 1 - .006669, as @Chris K said.

Comment: The answer for $1$ hour cannot be $0.006669$, nor can it be $1-0.006669$. One could play around and decide what the time interval might be if the answer is right. Something like $30$ seconds might be ballpark right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Poisson random variable that describes the number of cars in one hour with $\lambda = 540$. Then:

$P(X\ge11)=1-P(X<11)=1-P(X=10)-P(X=9)-...-P(X=0)$

where $P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}$

Comment: Note that I had the wrong lambda until I edited it. Also, I'm assuming you are asking for the probability that there are at least 11 cars in a given hour.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the random variable of the number of cars passing through the intersection in the time interval of $T$ hours. The probability of exactly $n$ cars crossing the intersection equals:
$$
   \Pr(X=n) = \frac{(\mu T)^n}{n!} \mathrm{e}^{-\mu T}
$$
where $\mu = 540 \frac{\text{cars}}{\text{hour}}$. The event that $A = \{X \geqslant 11\}$ is complementary to $B = \{0 \leqslant X \leqslant 10\}$, and hence $\Pr(A) + \Pr(B) = 1$:
$$
    \Pr(X \geqslant 11) = 1-\Pr(0 \leqslant X \leqslant 10) = 1 - \sum_{m=0}^{10} \Pr(X=m)
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that the probability is 1 - 0.006669?

I'm assuming you're talking about the probability of 11 or more cars in an hour.

The probability of 1 or more cars is simply:

$$1 - exp(-540).$$

The probability of 2 or more cars is:

$$1 - exp(-540) \cdot (1 + 540).$$

The probability of 11 or more cars is:

$$1 - exp(-540) \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{10}\frac{540^{i}}{i!}.$$

This answer is going to be very close to 1, which intuitively makes sense.